# Ccocs2d-Durations in actions withDurations

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action, duration

Let's take the following code:

```
    CCTintTo *tint1 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:4 red:255 green:0 blue:0];
    CCTintTo *tint2 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:4 red:0 green:0 blue:255];
    CCTintTo *tint3 = [CCTintTo actionWithDuration:4 red:0 green:255 blue:0];
    CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:tint1, tint2, tint3, nil];
    CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence];
    CCSpeed *speedAction = [CCSpeed actionWithAction:repeat speed:10];
```

As you can see the first three actions are the actions to tint to Red, Blue and Green respectively in 4 seconds. And then, the sequence of these actions are passed to a CCSpeed action with the speed of 10.Now what I can't understand at all is how these durations work? I mean, first three ones should complete in 4 seconds but the speed method is fast and does not let them last that much. What is the principle I should be aware of in terms of the durations of actions in cases like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, CCSpeed action just changes the whole time of CCActionInterval inside it. It means, that if your sequence's duration is 12 seconds, by passing this sequence to the CCSpeed action with speed 10, this sequence's duration will increase from 12 seconds to 120 seconds.

Another one point is that CCSpeed action waits CCActionInterval subclass in `actionWithAction:speed:` method. So, you cannot pass CCRepeatForever action to it. If you want to repeat forever this action, you should make your calls like

```
CCSequence *sequence = [CCSequence actions:tint1, tint2, tint3, nil];
CCSpeed* speedAction = [CCSpeed actionWithAction:sequence speed:10];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:speedAction];
```

Comment: The speed increases as the number increases. As per what you say I had to wait for two minutes for the whole sequence to complete.But it completed faster. So it's not 10 times slower but 10 times faster. And also, the above code is from the tutorial book "Learn cocos2d Game Development with iOS 5".

Comment: Really? Dude, I prefer to believe to the documentation rather than to you. From the CCSpeed documentation it "Changes the speed of an action, making it take longer (speed>1) or less (speed<1) time.". And again, from the documentation, constructor of the CCSpeed action is `+ (id) actionWithAction:(CCActionInterval *)action speed:(float) rate`, CCRepeatForever is not CCActionInterval subclass.

Comment: And I think one practice worths hundreds theories. I practiced it and got exactly what I told you. Didn't you mean I had to wait two minutes? But I did not. Instead it happened momentarily.Don't know why you got angry but I did not want to cause your nerves.

Comment: I'm not angry. I know a couple of things, that are worked, but from documentation, they cannot. These things are bugs. And one day someone wil fix them.